# API for getting medicine detail from UPC bar code

Tags: api, barcode

I need to implement an API which can fetch the medicine detail from UPC bar code. All the solutions i got on web are providing ways to read the bar code but I did not found any such API which could get me the product information like medicine Name, Manufacturer, Dosage, Expiry, Batch No etc form the bar code.

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you're operating in the US, usually the UPC is actually a shortened version of the [NDC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_Drug_Code), usually with the "extraneous" 0's left out. You need to convert to NDC and then look that data up against a drug database, like the [FDA database](https://open.fda.gov/). Usually however, pharmacies will buy a database from one of the drug database suppliers (e.g. Etreby or Elsevier) because those are curated and have a lot more detail and are usually easier to work with for the sorts of queries a pharmacy might want to make.

Edit: Per my comment below, it looks like you can query the FDA database via UPC without converting to NDC first.

Comment: I know we can use FDA database but I don't want to do the UPC search manually, rather I need some API references which could accept the UPC and get me all the medication details.

Comment: @SonuK That's exactly what the FDA database is. For example this: https://api.fda.gov/drug/label.json?search=openfda.upc=0843736010079 will return a json result with details. You're even able to search against the UPC directly without converting to NDC

Comment: The FDA database seems to be incomplete so I wouldn't rely on it. For example 300694210304 is a valid UPC-A for Viagra 50mg, but returns no matches: https://api.fda.gov/drug/label.json?search=openfda.upc=300694210304 But if you convert that UPC to package NDC 0069-4210-30 you will find it: https://api.fda.gov/drug/label.json?search=openfda.package_ndc=%220069-4210-30%22